# pass a delegate as param in function not allowing call of delegate

Tags: c#

I want to make this function work in my program, but Visual Studio tells me that MyFunc is a variable but is used like a method, But that's what I'm trying to do.  trying to call it.

```
static private void TryThisFunc(Delegate MyFunc)
{
   try
   {
       MyFunc(); // MyFunc is a variable but is used like a method
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Strongly suggest you get into the habit of using ex.ToString() and not ex.Message. The former includes much more useful information about the exception.

Comment: Passing in Delegate as the type is the same as using the keyword "class" as the type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't specified what *type* of delegate to use. It could be a delegate which takes parameters - in which case clearly you can't call it with no arguments. You probably want to use a *specific* delegate type, e.g.

```
static private void TryThisFunc(Action action)
{
    try
    {
        action();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh gosh, I can't believe I made this mistake.  Thanks, I understand.